# mysql - C# throws user not exit excemption in a transaction

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I am running a MySQL transaction in C# and getting failed to run the second query. I get an exemption on the following line:

`int no = sql_loc.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
db_local = "SERVER=localhost; Database=sync_r; UID=kandy; Password=kandy500;allow user variables=true";

MySqlConnection con_local = new MySqlConnection(db_local);
con_local.Open();

delq = "delete from tbl_recipes";  // all records
query = "insert into tbl_recipes(cat_id) values(6)";

MySqlTransaction tran = con_local.BeginTransaction();
MySqlCommand sql_loc = con_local.CreateCommand();
sql_loc.Transaction = tran;

sql_loc.CommandText = delq;
sql_loc.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql_loc.CommandText = query;
int no = sql_loc.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (no == 1)
    sql_loc.Transaction.Commit();
else
    sql_loc.Transaction.Rollback();
```

the error thrown is below

```
{"The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist"}
```

but this is not the user I have specified. How can I fix this?? Where the actual issue can be?

Comment: Check the user in the database

Comment: Does the `tbl_recipes` table have a trigger? You can run `SHOW TRIGGERS` in the mysql client. I expect the trigger was defined by `root@%` but that user no longer exists on your instance. Or perhaps `tbl_recipes` is a view, and views also have a definer.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes, there was a trigger and that was the cause. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments above, the error comes from a trigger that tries to adopt the identity of its definer when it executes, but the definer ('root'@'%') no longer exists on the the MySQL instance.

A workaround is to create that user (even if you create it and then disable authentication).

We do this at my place of employment. We define triggers and stored procedures and views using a special user with SUPER privilege, even though we do never use that user for any database access. We create other MySQL users for apps and individual developers, but do not grant SUPER privilege to those users.